# How to add Matplotlib graph to my pyqt layout

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, pyqt

Currently, I am working on an application using PYQT combo box selection application. The selection from the combo box has:

1. Textbox (Which just let user type on)
2. Image (To let the user drag and drop image to view image)
3. Audio (To let the user drag and drop the audio file to see spectrum
   graph plotted from matplotlib) - only can use wav files.

Everything work except the audio part. When I drag and drop my wav files, this happens.
[image: Graph being pushed down!]

I understand why it's pushed down. It's because there is a layout above. So my question is how do I  put it to that "lastWidget" layout? So that it can be shown in the same layout as my textbox and image. I tried adding it to another variable and do an add widget and also tried to do pixmap. However, I just can't seem to get it to work.

```
import sys, os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 

#audio plot on pyqt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import *
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class UI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Programme")
        self.setFixedSize(600, 600)

        central = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(central)

        combo = QComboBox(self)
        combo.addItems(("textbox", "image", "audio"))
        combo.setFixedSize(200, 30)
        self.layout.addWidget(combo)

        self.lastWidget = QLineEdit(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lastWidget)
        self.lastWidget.setFixedSize(500, 500)
        combo.activated[str].connect(self.onChanged)  

        self.show()

    def onChanged(self, text):

        if text == 'textbox':
            self.layout.removeWidget(self.lastWidget)
            self.lastWidget.deleteLater()

            self.lastWidget = QLineEdit()
            self.lastWidget.setFixedSize(500, 500)

        elif text == 'image':
            self.layout.removeWidget(self.lastWidget)
            self.lastWidget.deleteLater()
            #Doing drag and drop for image
            self.lastWidget = DragAndDropImage()
            self.layout.addWidget(self.lastWidget)

        elif text == 'audio':

            self.layout.removeWidget(self.lastWidget)
            self.lastWidget.deleteLater()
            #Doing drag and drop for Audio
            self.lastWidget = DragAndDropAudio()
            self.layout.addWidget(self.lastWidget)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.lastWidget)
        
        QApplication.processEvents()
        self.adjustSize()

class DragAndDropAudio(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setFixedSize(500, 500)
 
    
    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        event.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasUrls:
            file_path = event.mimeData().urls()[0].toLocalFile()
            # print(file_path)
            self.set_audio(file_path)
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore() 
    
    def set_audio(self, file_path):
        canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(5, 4)))
        ax = canvas.figure.subplots()
        # fig, self.ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=120)
        t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
        s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
        # read audio samples
        input_data = read(file_path)
        audio = input_data[1]
        # plot the first 1024 samples
        ax.plot(audio[0:1024])
        # label the axes   
        ax.plot(t, s)
        ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='Amlitude',
               title='Audio Spectrum')

        ex.layout.addWidget(canvas)
        

class DragAndDropImage(QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setFixedSize(500, 500)
        self.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setText('\n\n Drop Image Here (InputImage) \n\n')
        self.setStyleSheet('''
            QLabel{
                border: 4px dashed #aaa
            }
        ''')

    def setPixmap(self, image):
        super().setPixmap(image)
    
    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasImage:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasImage:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasImage:
            event.setDropAction(Qt.CopyAction)
            file_path = event.mimeData().urls()[0].toLocalFile()
            self.set_image(file_path)
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore() 
    
    def set_image(self, file_path):
        ex.lastWidget.setPixmap(QPixmap(file_path))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = UI()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not add and remove widgets, in this case it is better to use QStackedWidget.

```py
class UI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Programme")
        self.setFixedSize(600, 600)

        central = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central)

        self.combo = QComboBox()
        self.combo.setFixedSize(200, 30)

        self.textbox = QLineEdit()
        self.textbox.setFixedSize(500, 500)
        self.dnd_image = DragAndDropImage()
        self.dnd_audio = DragAndDropAudio()

        self.stacked_widget = QStackedWidget()
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.textbox)
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.dnd_image)
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.dnd_audio)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(central)
        layout.addWidget(self.combo)
        layout.addWidget(self.stacked_widget)

        self.combo.addItem("textbox", self.textbox)
        self.combo.addItem("image", self.dnd_image)
        self.combo.addItem("audio", self.dnd_audio)

        self.combo.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.onChanged)
        self.show()

    def onChanged(self):
        widget = self.combo.currentData()
        if isinstance(widget, QWidget):
            self.stacked_widget.setCurrentWidget(widget)
        self.adjustSize()
```

Comment: Thanks! I swapped it out and it worked!